# Javascript and href in anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, window, href, target

Can JavaScript see the target name of a window that was opened by a regular "href".  Here is an example:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blanknewWindow" name="NewWindowName">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(window.name);
```

will contain the target name.